# How to define a static pointer to a file stream?

Tags: c++, pointers, static

I need a static pointer to a output file stream. With this code:

```
#include <fstream>

class Test {
public:
    static std::ofstream *sOfs;
};

std::ofstream Test::*sOfs;

int main()
{
    Test::sOfs = new std::ofstream("test.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following linker error:

```
In function `main':
source_file.cpp: undefined reference to `Test::sOfs'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

If the member is not static, the build is fine.
Is it possible to define a static pointer to a stream at all? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax should be

```
std::ofstream* Test::sOfs;
```

For `std::ofstream Test::*sOfs`, you're defining a global variable named `sOfs`, with type of [non-static data member pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) points to member with type `std::ofstream` of class `Test`.